# opengl es 2.0 source code location in android source code

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I need to find the code of glLinkProgram() method because there is a weird behavior happening when I call it (it never returns). I downloaded the whole source code and now I have to find where is the OpenGL ES 2.0 code location. I only found the frameworks/base/jni bindings but I can't yet locate the meat. Can you help me with this, please?

Answer (score 0):

There's likely not any meat to be found in the android source code. OpenGL calls like glLinkProgram are handled in the GPU's OpenGL driver, which I'm pretty sure is proprietary and you won't find the source code for it. The best you're likely find in android is just a simple wrapper around a glLinkProgram call to the GPU driver, which probably doesn't do anything interesting.

Sorry to hear you're having that problem, what kind of phone/gpu are you using? Are you determining that it's not returning by using the debugger and stepping into it, and it just hangs the whole system?

Have you confirmed that both shaders compiled successfully before trying to link them? You shouldn't be seeing this behavior either way, but it might be good to know.

I'll look at the code in your [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660759/gles20-gllinkprogram-call-in-android-does-not-return) if you want to put it up there.

Comment: I use the android emulator. The GLThread simply remains unresponsive so GLSurfaceView is dead. The other threads seem to be working though. I haven't checked whether the shaders compiled succesfully since I lifted them from RenderMonkey (Plastic.rfx). But it should return regardless...

Comment: Yes it should return, but maybe you found a bug in the emulator by doing something 'unusual'. GLES2.0 support is relatively new.

Comment: Ok I checked and the shaders compile..although adding a comment in the shader makes it not compile anymore... is this behavior normal? Not compiling if // in code?

Comment: If it fails to compile, check the info log, it should tell you why it has not compiled. See glGetShaderInfoLog

Comment: So if I include a comment in code I get:Vertex shader failed to compile with the following errors:
ERROR: 0:1: error(#131) Syntax error: pre-mature EOF parse error
ERROR: error(#273) 1 compilation errors.  No code generated
If I get rid of comments it compiles but still doesn't come back from linking...

Comment: I should probably add that I am both compiling and linking in the method onDrawFrame() not in onSurfaceCreated/Changed().

Comment: Is it a duplicate of this other question always from you?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660759/gles20-gllinkprogram-call-in-android-does-not-return